# Export to COLLADA with textures using Cycles renderer

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, export, collada

I'm trying to export a Blender model which is created using the Cycles renderer in Blender. The problem is that it does not successfully export as a `.dae` file. The image references and images are missing. What is the correct way to export a Blender model to a COLLADA file?